# Laravel deployment with deployer fails updating shared/.env file

Tags: laravel, deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

Im quite new to laravel and the concept of CI/CD. But i have invested the last 24 hours to get something up and running. Actually i'm using gitlab.com as repo. There i have configured the CI/CD functionality.

The deployments should be done to SRV1 which has configured its corresponding user with a cert. The SRV1 should then clone the necessary files from the gitlab repo by using deployer. The gitlab repo also has the public key from SRV1 user. This chain is working quite good

The problem now is, that i want to update the .env file placed under shared/.env using the .gitlab-ci.yml file. But for some reasons, this won't work:

Here is my file: https://pastebin.com/RsjQf9L3

Basically, the deployment is done by this command sequence:

```
- cp .env.staging .env
- php artisan key:generate
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan deploy dev.morast.ch -s upload
```

I thought, that wen doing

```
- cp .env.staging .env
```

It will replace the content of shared/.env with the content of .env.staging
In fact, the file gets replaced (i see it due to the date code) but the content don't equals the .env.staging file.

What do i wrong? Thanks for your help.

By the way, i always get an

```
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

Maybe this could also be related to my .gitlab-ci.yml  file?

thanks!

Comment: I use the command `mv .env.staging .env`. Im not sure what differences they have. Also you might not want to call `key:generate` on every deployment, because changing the key renders all previously encrypted data undecryptable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you also use lorisleiva/laravel-deployer for deployment? And do you do your mv at the exactly same position like i do? Thanks for the hint with key:generate. That could be the root cause of my second problem.

Comment: Just tried out to replace the cp with the mv command and commented out the key:generate. But it didnt changed anything. The shared/.env file is still the same and the error message about the key persists.

Comment: I cant tell if youre checking the wrong file or not. `mv .env.staging .env` simply moves the `.env.staging` to `.env`, so if the `.env` appears to be wrong, then your `.env.staging` is wrong. Be sure to check the output that gitlab generates. I dont use the laravel-deployer, i simply use `rsync` to upload files to an SSH endpoint. Theres no need to use a php package for that. I can post the config as an answer with some annotations if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw, that in my shared/.env file there are two keys concated together... Dont know why. After running php artisan key:generate and artisan config:cache on the remote machine, the page was working. that was the reason why i added these commands to the ci file. But still no chance to get the shared/.env file copied from my .env.staging